# Wpf mvvm datagrid EditingCellEvent OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, mvvm, datagrid, out-of-memory, catel

I have grid in a WPF window and a DataGrid control inside:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridDataContent"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          Background="White"
          BorderBrush="#FFE6E6E6"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ProductCollection}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
                                 Opacity="0.5"
                                 Color="DodgerBlue" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrush}" Color="DodgerBlue" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="350"
                            Binding="{Binding FullName}"
                            Header="Name"
                            IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductSale.Barcode}"
                            Header="Barcode"
                            IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}"
                            Header="Quantity"
                            IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding WriteOffQuantity}"
                            Header="Writeoff quantity"
                            IsReadOnly="False" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

when you click the writeoff 2 times, the devenv.exe process takes a lot of memory and continuously growing, then Visual Studio 2015 closed crash exception there OutOfMemoryException.
ProductCollection is of type ObservableCollection < ProductModel >, the number of records is not more than 1000.
In what may be a problem?
P.S. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Does the Diagnostics window from VS 2015 give any clue?

Comment: in diagnostic mode without debug the application works well.
in debug mode, the application takes 100-150Mb.

Comment: Might be a VS isse and nothing to do with your application.  Do a reinstall of visual studio (it's easy, just install over your current copy).  Also, there's a russian version of stackoverflow--ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I'am using click once technology, after the publication of the application also it takes a lot of memory, and it grows. in the Russian version, too, I will write, thank you